# Totals by product in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with products ordered for today.
It is grouped by a delivery methods like this

```
**Delivery method #1**
Product #1    100
Product #2    150

**Delivery method #2**
Product #1   200
Product #2   100
```

I am wondering if there is a way to add new table to the end of the report with totals for each product, for all delivery methods, like this:

```
**Total**
Product #1    300
Product #2    250
```

Is there a way to do this in crystal report?

Thanks.

Comment: where do you need the final summary at row level or at column level

Comment: I want to summarize all products from variuos delivery methods at the end of the report...